# Watching DOM state in AngularJS directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have two related problems with directives which depend on DOM state set by other directives.

In the first example I want to set a class based on the presence of another class (to apply Bootstrap styles to an input).

Demo: http://codepen.io/tamlyn/pen/jPNWQR

Excerpt from directive:

```
  scope.$watch(function(){
    return el.hasClass('ng-invalid');
  }, function(isInvalid) {
    el.toggleClass('also-invalid', isInvalid);
  })
```

The problem is that the `also-valid` class is one digest cycle behind. Initially it is unset when it should be set, then typing a character in the box sets the class when it should be unset, then further characters unset it again. This is presumably due to the order in which the watches are triggered and the fact that the DOM changes don't trigger further iterations. It doesn't seem to be affected by the directive's `priority`.

In the second example I want to set a class based on the element's width.

Demo: http://codepen.io/tamlyn/pen/BNBjbq

Excerpt from directive:

```
  scope.$watch(function(){
    return el[0].clientWidth;
  }, function(width) {
    el.toggleClass('wide', width > 300);
  })
```

The problem is the same: the class is one iteration behind.

What am I doing wrong and how should I be doing it?

Comment: This is in a directive? Try adding `$scope.$apply()`?

Comment: So if I add this: `console.log('class', el.hasClass('expanded'));` inside the first watch function, it logs false (the first time, I mean). So, it looks like the ng-class evaluates _after_ your directive.